# Selecting XPATH of all Divs that contains certain attribute using Scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

Assume given HTML

```
<div class="class_A">
   <div class="class_B" index=value >
       ...a lot going on...
   </div> 
</div>
```

If know I can select all divs by their class name as:

```
'//div[contains(@class,'class_B')]'
```

But I want to access divs with a specific attribute such as `index` (with any value).

**Just to clarify:** We have to select div that has `index` as an attribute, not by a specific value of `index`.
Any help would highly be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use simple xpath.

```
//div[@index]
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: Related question, how about if he wants div[@class="class_B"] if it has index?

Comment: Do you mean getting the xpath `//tag[@class='value']` based on the element which has the `index`?

Comment: Yes, we can. But it's a crude way and not sure why you want to do it, as you already located the element using other xpath. Anyhow, here is the approach. `element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@index]')` then build the xpath `xpath = "//" + element.tag_name + "[@class='" + element.get_attribute('class') + "']"`. You can `print(xpath)` and check the output.

Comment: this is definitely not pretty but I am sure it has its uses when div with similar class names but not all attributes. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

you can use Scrapy shell and test this expression
`response.xpath("//*[contains(@class,'class_B')]").getall()`